# Does a cookie load for every file downloaded on a Web page?

Tags: php, cookies

If I have a general cookie applicable to a whole site (eg. stackoverflow.com), does that cookie get downloaded only for each Web page load, or does it get downloaded for every file downloaded on that Web page (such as image files)?

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is just additional information provided in the Header part of a HTTP request.

Setting a cookie happens by including the line

```
Set-Cookie: key=value
```

in the HTTP response from the server to the client. It only needs to be set once and stays in the browser unless cookie storage is cleared.

Cookies can also automatically expire if needed

```
Set-Cookie: key=value; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

If a cookie for a site is set, the client includes it in every request to the server, adding something like this to the request header

```
Cookie: key=value
```

If and for which files the Set-Cookie header is added depends on the configuration of your server and your web application.

Does this answer your question?

You may also find the Wikipedia article covering cookies useful:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: Are you confirming that every file (eg. img, css, jss) downloaded from the server on a Webpage also downloads all cookies with the same directory path?

Comment: That depends on how you set the cookie. If you set the cookie using your webserver, e.g. Apache, and configure it to set it for each accessed file, then yes, every server response will have the cookie information included.

Comment: If you set it in your application, e.g. with PHP, JavaScript, Python..., then it is only included for all requests that are handled by the application, not for direct file requests. Direct file requests would be the default case for css, js and images, but you can also configure your webserver to route those requests through your application code as well.